# Get snapshot from streaming video (newbie)

Tags: c#, video-streaming, video-processing, emgucv

I have a video player written using Emgu (a .net wrapper for OpenCV) and I am capture the frames and performing some operations on certan frames. In on functionality, I let the user  take a snapshot of a streaming video and highlight sections of the snapshot in a different form.

However, since the video player is playing underneath the image on the child form is also updated as the user draws on the form. This is undesirable. I am pretty sure this has something to do with my locking and unlocking stuff and I am a newbie to this stuff.

Any ideas where I am going wrong? I would have thought the **lock (bmpFrame)** would have prevented any updates, but it doesn't:

```
 private void btnTag_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_video != null && _video.CurrentFrame != null)
        {
            try
            {
                using (Bitmap bmpFrame = (Bitmap)_video.CurrentFrame.Bitmap)
                {
                    lock (bmpFrame)
                    {
                        TagForm f = new TagForm(bmpFrame);
                        f.Show();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch { };
        }
    }
```

Comment: `lock(obj)` simply prevents more than one `lock(obj)` clause from executing at any point in time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ahhh! silly me, it was indeed a oversight. Fixed by allocating new memory for the new bitmap

```
using (Bitmap bmpFrame = new Bitmap(_video.CurrentFrame.Bitmap)
{

   lock (bmpFrame)
   {
       TagForm f = new TagForm(bmpFrame);
       f.Show();
   }

}
```

Comment: Hope this is of some help to some newbie in my position.